# Create a click event with ".on" based on element class excluding certain elements

Tags: jquery

I need to bind a click event to the elements with class '.rows', but I want to 
exclude one of them bearing the id '#unsigned'.

I am using ON command like this:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.rows', (a_function_to_run));
```

I was expecting this:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.rows',':not(#unsigned)', (a_function_to_run));
```

or this

```
$('.container').on('click', '.rows', (a_function_to_run)).not('#unsigned');
```

to work.

What is the right syntax? 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) in the selector:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.rows:not(#unsigned)', function() { ... });
```